# No data in Firebase custom property even after a day

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am setting user property, but I am not getting any data in the Firebase console.:

1. I have registred **favorite_food** as a user property in firebase console.
2. I am using below code to register event and setting property

   ```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "TempId");
   bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "TempName Oncreate");
   bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
   mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT,bundle);

   mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("favorite_food", "INDIAN FOOD");
   ```
3. I waited for a day after executing the code, but I haven't received any data in my custom property. Below is the log I am getting from Firebase service. Please help me.

   ```
   02-06 11:04:25.469 7341-24523/test.testfcm D/FA: Setting user property (FE): favorite_food, pizza

   02-06 11:04:25.489 7341-24523/test.testfcm V/FA: Using measurement service

   02-06 11:04:25.489 7341-24523/test.testfcm V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress

   02-06 11:04:25.489 7341-24523/test.testfcm V/FA: Using measurement service

   02-06 11:04:25.489 7341-24523/test.testfcm V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress

   02-06 11:04:25.489 7341-24523/test.testfcm V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1093679

   02-06 11:04:25.519 7341-24523/test.testfcm D/FA: Connected to remote service

   02-06 11:04:25.529 7341-24523/test.testfcm V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 3

   02-06 11:04:25.609 1300-24541/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='test.testfcm', name='select_content', params=Bundle[{item_name=TempName Oncreate, _o=app, content_type=image, item_id=TempId}]}

   02-06 11:04:30.599 7341-24523/test.testfcm V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

   02-06 11:14:25.449 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 600010

   02-06 11:14:25.449 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Using measurement service

   02-06 11:14:25.449 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Connecting to remote service

   02-06 11:14:25.459 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1693688

   02-06 11:14:25.479 7341-3377/test.testfcm D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=600010, _sc=MainActivity, _si=367007112786571721}]

   02-06 11:14:25.489 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Using measurement service

   02-06 11:14:25.489 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress

   02-06 11:14:25.509 7341-3377/test.testfcm D/FA: Connected to remote service

   02-06 11:14:25.509 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2

   02-06 11:14:25.559 1300-3389/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='test.testfcm', name='_e', params=Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=600010, _sc=MainActivity, _si=367007112786571721}]}

   02-06 11:14:30.539 7341-3377/test.testfcm V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
   ```

Comment: It would be nice to see the log information both before and after the excerpt you provided above.  For instance, there would have been an earlier line along the lines of "App measurement is starting up, version: ####".  That would be nice to see.  Did it eventually upload your event?  The debug lines that dump the event bundle would also be nice to see.  Those lines start with "Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data:"

Comment: I don't see the user property "favorite_food" attached to the events. Do you always set the user property when you log the events? Once you set a user property, it will always attach to all events until you remove it.

Comment: @DanMorenus Thanks for replying... First time I received only these lines in a log. After I tried on other phones I got a new log with json key value pair with Uploading data. But thanks for the input. It really helped me.

Comment: @AlexD Thanks for replying.. Yes I was setting UserProperty whenever there was a log event. I changed only one thing now. I think I should have called setuserproperty() before logging an event. I changed it now and its working.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting user property after logging an event. It should be before logging any event. I changed the code as below and its working.

```
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("favorite_food", "INDIAN FOOD");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "TempId");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "TempName Oncreate");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT,bundle);
```